# How to add a property in a string to an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Given the following object:

```
var obj = { a: 1 };
```

and the following string:

```
var s = "b: 2";
```

what I need is to end with the following object, after evaluating the string s:

```
obj === { a:1, b:2 }
```

I tried with `eval` but couldn't figure it out. any ideas?

Comment: Do u want to compare object with string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Eval can be harmful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) so instead try something like this

```
var obj = { a: 1 };
var s = "b: 2";
s = s.replace(/\s/g, '').split(":");
obj[s[0]] = s[1];
```

```js
var obj = { a: 1 };
var s = "b: 2";
s = s.replace(/\s/g, '').split(":");
obj[s[0]] = s[1];
alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically set object properties by using this notation obj[propName] = value. In your case I used substring to cut up your value and property name.

```
obj[s.substring(0,1)] = s.substring(3,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also work for multiple key value pair in string.

```
 var obj = {a: 1};
    str = "b: 2";
    var strArr = str.split(',');
    for (var index in strArr) {
        var strMap = strArr[index].split(':');
        obj[strMap[0].trim()] = parseInt(strMap[1].trim());
    }
```

Here, Simply I split the string into array and then traverse through it and generate required map.

Answer (score 0):

`eval()` treats string as normal code so you can just return desired value by using `return` keyword.

### ```js
    var expression = "{b:2}";
    var expString = "return " + expression + ";"

    // returns Object{ b : 2 }
    alert(eval("(function() {" + expString + "}())").b);
```

Note:

1. `eval()` is considered as a high risk function, it can be use to exploit your solution.
2. Have you heard of `JSON` data model ? [check it here](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_intro.asp) .